# How to connect router to internet through a PC with 3G modem?

Tags: windows-xp, router, android

I want to connect my android to internet through my PC which have 3G Internet connection like this diagram :

```
+------------+
| Android    |
|  Device    |
+--------|---+      
      (( | ))
              WiFi
                                 +--------------+
      (( | ))                    |   Windows XP |
+--------|-----+                 |       PC     |             +-----------+
|              |                 |              |             |  3G modem |    Internet
|  Router      +-----------------+              +-------------+           +---- Access
|192.168.1.1   |     Ethernet    |              |   PPP(DHCP) |           |  
+--------------+                 |              |             +-----------+
                                 +--------------+
```

The problem is that I can't do this in Windows, but in Ubuntu it works with:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o ppp0 -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using the command line, setup Internet Connection Sharing (ICS).

[How to configure Internet Connection Sharing in Windows XP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306126)